# How to configure nginx to refuse connection from a suspicious host?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I use Nginx to handle HTTP requests. During access log inspection, I found a lot of suspicious requests from the same IP address.
I'd like to configure Nginx to refuse connections from hosts like that one; I don't think that there will be a lot of hosts because it was the first one for years.

Comment: Fail2Ban or you can add and manage a blacklist

Answer (score 2):

This is basically how the Nginx geo-ip module works, I've done a similar thing to whitelist Google crawlers on my sites.

In your `http` block define a `geo` directive and add the CIDR ip ranges you wish to block:

```
geo $badips {
  default 0;
  64.233.160.0/19 1;
  66.102.0.0/20 1;
  ...
}
```

This will set the value of variable `$badips` to `1` for requests originating from those ip addresses.

Then in your `server` block, before any `location` blocks, add:

```
if ($badips) {
  return 444;
}
```

Reload Nginx and that's it, requests which trigger `$bdips` to be set to 1 will be server a 444 response code (you can change it to another if you prefer).

If you want to keep the banned addresses in a different file then you can do that and inside the `geo` directive just add `include path/to/file;`. Syntax within the included file must be the same as above.

Comment: Worth noting that there is no standard HTTP status code `444`. It's a non-standard Nginx extension. When you ask Nginx to return 444 (from its configuration via `return` or from an application), it simply drops HTTP connection w/o any response.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention that.

Comment: [nginx documentation on 444](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)